# MySQL query returns a false value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a menu using the data from a database table. But I have a little problem. My query results return a false boolean value.

This is my code:

```
<?php
class DataBase
{
    protected $dbUser;
    protected $dbPassword;
    protected $dbHost;
    protected $dbName;
    protected $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbUser     = 'root';
        $this->dbPassword = '';
        $this->dbHost     = 'localhost';
        $this->dbName     = 'ecommercemakup';
        $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName) or die('Fatal error!');
    }

    public function getInstance()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }
}
?>

<?php
$db = new DataBase();
$r  = mysqli_query($db->getInstance(), "CALL categories()");
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<li> <a href=' . $row['name'] . '.php>';
        print_r($row['name']);
        echo '</a>
            <ul>';
        $id = intval($row['idCategory']);
        $r1 = mysqli_query($db->getInstance(), "CALL subcategories($id)");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r1) > 0) {
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($r1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<li><a href=' . $row1['name'], '.php>';
                print_r($row1['name']);
                echo '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul></li>';
    }
}
?>
```

The first query runs correctly, but the second query always return false.

The two procedures are this:

```sql
DELIMITER @@
DROP PROCEDURE categories @@
CREATE PROCEDURE ecommercemakup.categories()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM categories;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ; 

DELIMITER @@
DROP PROCEDURE subcategories @@
CREATE PROCEDURE ecommercemakup.subcategories
(IN id_Category INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT idSubcategory, idCategory, name FROM subcategories WHERE idCategory = id_Category;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

The `categories` table contains 2 items: `idCategory` and `name`, and the `subcategories` table contain 3 items: `idSubcategory`, `idCategory` and `name`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try running the procedure from MySQL command line? Just to check either it is a MySQL or PHP problem.

Comment: Better suited for [DBA SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: I tried it and it runs correctly

Comment: Why do you use procedures for these simple queries?

Comment: Could it be that your `intval` changes the id to an id that doesn't exist? or maybe the id starts with 0 so it doesn't find it?

Comment: have you tried adding `'` to your id variable?:  `$r1 = mysqli_query($db->getInstance(), "CALL subcategories('$id')");`

Comment: My id start with 1 and in first time I tried without, and the result whast the same

Comment: You can debug by changing `$id = intval($row['idCategory']);` for `$id=1;` and see if it works.

Comment: I receive the same result

Comment: Please note that the [The mysqli class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) has an [error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the variable name to `@id_Category`, you are missing @ before the name.

In MySQL, @variable indicates a user-defined variable. You can define your own.

SET @a = 'test';
SELECT @a;

A variable, without @, is a system variable, which you cannot define yourself.
This is causing problem for you, as you are declaring variable without `@`

Hope it helps

REFER

[User defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

[System variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html)